# Multiple Website can use same home page and same database, but not need to change the url?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, .htaccess, web-hosting

i have a multiple websites domains  like example1.com, example2.com, example3.com and so on, and there domain on different servers, some on same server and some on another server.  If user go for expample1.com, empample2.com and so on... then user land on index.php which is common for all websites and using common database for all websites.

Answer (score 0):

This can work, you just have to use relative URLs in your links, so instead of doing

`<a href="http://example1.com/index.php">Home</a>`

You would do ...

`<a href="/index.php">Home</a>`

This way, the browser will put in the domain that the page is on for you.

You can also use this technique for links for CSS documents in the head, or links to JavaScript resources, as long as the directory structure is the same as well across all of the sites.

Comment: Thanks Mark, But i want one common home page for all my websites, and there domain on different server, is it possible make one page for all websites?

Comment: Yes, you use the same file, but you change all of the resources it  links too from absolute URLs to relative ones as shown above. Tell me what part, what part you don't understand and I'll go over it in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

forward them all with masking. you would just have to decide which website will host the website and then the rest are simply forwarded

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/422/forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name